# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'

Tags: c#, log4net

Below code throw exception :

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

[image]

and i tried to install package but it could not
[image]

Comment: Hi J_Shrestha and welcome to stackoverflow! Please reformat your question. You should **never** include images of code - just copy the code and format it properly. also try to describe what you are doing to get the above error.

Comment: just modified the question

Answer (score 4):

**.NET version 4.5.2**
*Solution explorer*, right click *References* -> *Add reference...*

In the new window choose *Assemblies* and fill in "System.configuration" in the search box. Is the checkbox checked? 
If not, hover over it, select it.
[image: Reference Manager]

**.NET version 4.6.1**
It could be that you forgot to add the nugget package?

In the *solution explorer*, right click *References*, choose *Manage Nugget Packages..*

[image: How to open Nugget package manager]

Under the *Browse*, fill in "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager".
Choose the one from Microsoft and see what the tab on the right says. Install if not already installed.
[image: Nugget Package manager overview]

Comment: i tried it but could not install package in .net framework 4.5.2

Comment: but requirement is .net framework 4.5.2 so cannot switch that.

Comment: The system.configuration.configurationmanager package seems to only have a depency on .NET 4.6.1
Hmm, what now

Comment: Can you check if the reference is added? I edited the answer to explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A quick update that this may also happen when mixing .net core and .net framework assemblies.

In my case is was a .net framework test project referencing a mixture of .net standard and .net framework projects. Once I moved the test into a .net core test project the code runs fine.